# np.log() vs StandardScaler() in preprocessing of dataset variables

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, feature-engineering

I'm anew to DS and now I'm passing this [introductury Course](https://www.kaggle.com/learn/intro-to-deep-learning) on Kaggle. I'm trying to catch the logic behind [this exercise](https://www.kaggle.com/sergiyrazumov/exercise-stochastic-gradient-descent/edit), introduction. Particularly the part of data transformations is unclear:

```
preprocessor = make_column_transformer(
(StandardScaler(),
 make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number)),
(OneHotEncoder(sparse=False),
 make_column_selector(dtype_include=object)),)
X = preprocessor.fit_transform(X)
y = np.log(y) # log transform target instead of standardizing
```

Author chooses to apply StandardScaler() to numerical variables and np.log() transformation to target variable. Can you explain me please what's the reason for using np.log() transfromation?
Data itself looks like this (with 'FE' as target variable):
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance for all the possible answers an explanations!
If you suggest some articles to read to fill the gaps, I will be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Your notebook link was broken, so I couldn't check if the author pointed out a reason to implement log transformation. But, one typical use case of log-transform is with skewed distributions. So, taking the logarithm makes them a bit algorithm (and numerical) friendly.

This one (FE column, which seems to be the target variable) seems a bit skewed towards left. The minimum value is around 17, the first quartile (25% quantile) is at 29, median is about 34, and third quartile is about 39. But, the maximum value is around 70.

The rightmost portion with length 30 has only 25 % of the probability mass. The distribution won't be like an exponential or power-law distribution, but it contains a bit skew. Most probably, the author chooses to decrease it by taking the logarithm.

Comment: hey, gunes, thanks for the answer!
can you please describe a little on "the link was broken"? I'll try to change something for you... As for me it works perfectly...
https://monosnap.com/file/nMyVbB6zZ5QrAfhsfY85YAkQwmWjMO
Sorry, I miskicked the StandardScaler in the video above, but you surely got the idea...

Comment: Try to go to the link in incognito mode or when you're logged out from your Kaggle account.